# Correct syntax for PHP Cron Job in CPanel

Tags: php, email, cron

I wanted to send a simple email in php that can be triggered by CRON jobs in CPanel..

```
php /home/username/public_html/test/email.php
```

I am using the above script to run the script and send an email to me but no luck...

```
<?php
$to = "email@email.com";
$subject = "I'm CRON from CPanel";
$message = "Just wanna say that your cron is working";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

I am using the above PHP script as well..

Why is it that it is not sending email?

Comment: Does it work if you have the full path to php - what mail did you get in your web based user account? (not necessarily YOUR mail, but the one on your webserver)

Comment: what do you mean by full path to php by the way??

Comment: such as /usr/bin/php (or whereever it maybe on your web hoster, you can check php info for that)

Comment: /usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/mysite.com/email.php . This is the complete command that worked for me. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :- php -f /home/username/public_html/test/email.php
Also check your Home Directory  "/home/username" in cPanel

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me:

```
php /home/username/folder/script.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

As for your question "Why is it that it is not sending email?"

Considering it is being sent to email@email.com you would have no idea if it was or if it was not being sent anyways.

Comment: I just fabricated the email@email.com email to hide my true email :)